# Why is $p \land (p \lor q)$ equivalent to $p$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can you prove with equivalence laws that $p \land  (p\lor q)$ is equivalent to $p$?
I know you have to get rid of $q$, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To prove using equivalence laws, we need your list of equivalence laws. There are many possible "standard" lists.

Comment: I have to use laws like distributivity, De Morgan, True/False-elimination

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have:
\begin{align*}
p \wedge (p \vee q) &= (p \vee F) \wedge (p \vee q) & \text{identity for } \vee \\
&= p \vee (F \wedge q) & \text{distributivity of } \vee \text{ over } \wedge \\
&= p \vee F & \text{annihilator for } \wedge \\
&= p & \text{identity for } \vee.
\end{align*}

Comment: Note, that $F$ is an arbitrary false statement, such as $p \wedge \neg p$

Comment: thank you very much! That's what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

When proving simple tautologies like this one, I like to break it into cases: if $p$ is $T$ and if $p$ is $F$.

If $p$ is $T$, then we have $T \wedge (T\vee q) = T\wedge T = T$.

If $p$ is $F$, then we have $F \wedge (F\vee q) = F$.

Comment: This is usually what I do myself. A good approach!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a third way, - just pointing out, that there are several ways;

$$
\begin{align*} 
p\wedge (p\vee q)&\equiv (p\wedge p)\vee(p\wedge q)\ - \ Distributive \ law\\
&\equiv p\vee(p\wedge q) \ - \ Idempotent \ law\\
&\equiv p \ - \ Absorption \ law
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 3):

> I have to use laws like distributivity, De Morgan, True/False-elimination

In that case:
$$(p ∧ (p ∨ q)) ⇔ (p ∧ (p ∨ q)) ∨ (p ∧ ¬p) ⇔ (p ∧ ((p ∨ q) ∨ ¬p)) ⇔ p$$